# Unauthorized Orbeon Form Error

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am using orbeon xform engine as a separate deployment with my Java Application. I followed all the steps required for separate deployment but while implementing xfroms using Orbeon I am getting following error:

"Orbeon Forms - Unauthorized
You do not have access to this page."

Inside tomcat orbeon log file it is showing following error:

```
392 INFO  ProcessorService  - Context listener - Context initialized.
522 INFO  ProcessorService  - Servlet initialized.
724 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-renderer - Received request
192 INFO  PageFlowControllerProcessor  - unauthorized {controller: "oxf:/ops/xforms/xforms-renderer-page-flow.xml", method: "POST",  path: "/xforms-renderer", status-code: "403"}
205 INFO  ProcessorService  - /xforms-renderer - Timing: 2465
```

I used RequestDispatcher in my servlet to forward my request for required XForm

```
ServletContext context= getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd= context.getRequestDispatcher("/xforms-jsp/orbeon/form.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

I am able to render xfrom while implementing as a integrated deployment.

May you guide where I am getting wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Orbeon Forms are you using?

Comment: I am using Community Edition version 4.0.0 of Orbeon Forms.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [separate deployment](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-with-java-applications#TOC-Separate-deployment), you should be using the Orbeon servlet filter in your `web.xml`, and you don't need to use a `RequestDispatcher` in your own code. I double-checked this now with 4.0 to verify it works. (I am wondering what led you to believe that you needed to use your own `RequestDispatcher`, as I don't see anything about this in the separate deployment documentation.)

Note however that because of [this issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/877), for now you also need to add the `orbeon` class on the `<body>` of your HTML, otherwise the proper styles won't apply. This is just temporary, and the class will be added automatically for you when this issue is fixed.

Comment: I added Orbeon servlet filter in my web.xml file. But can you explain me how can I send my xform from my java application to orbeon other then RequestDispatcher method.

Comment: The servlet filter does this for you: it takes the output of your servlet, make it go through Orbeon Forms, and sends the result to the browser.